# Write text in particular font color in MS word using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to write text in an MS Word file using python library python-docx.
I have gone through the documentation of python-docx's font color [on this link](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/font-color.html) and applied the same in my code, but am unsuccessful so far.

Here is my code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph('some text').add_run()
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
p=document.add_paragraph('aaa')
document.save('demo1.docx')
```

The text in word file 'demo.docx' is simply in black color.

I am not able to figure this out, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have found the answer myself using python-docx docs,

Here is the correct code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run('some text')
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
p=document.add_paragraph('aaa')
document.save('demo1.docx')
```

'some text' is a parameter of add_run() function rather than add_paragraph() function.

The above code gives desired color.

Answer (score 4):

[`RGBColor`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shared.html#rgbcolor-objects)

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor

document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
run = paragraph.add_run('Red ')
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
run = paragraph.add_run('Green ')
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00)
run = paragraph.add_run('Blue')
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor.from_string('0000FF')
document.save('test.docx')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`font.color.rgb = RGBColor.from_string('FF0000')`

This will be handy to construct RGBColor.