# Get actual color of text in MS Word when python-docx returns none

Tags: python, colors, ms-word, python-docx

I am using the python-docx package to process some MS Word documents.  I need to figure out the color of some text.  To do this you can loop through the paragraphs and loop through the runs inside the paragraph and grab
`color = run.font.color.rgb`
The issue with this is that sometimes (often) this is `None`.

I found this post on github with an answer from @scanny, who I think manages the package:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/139
In this post he says that color can be inherited from styles.

I'm interested in understanding the inheritance path.  I know how to look at `color = run.style.font.color.rgb`, and `color = paragraph.style.font.rgb`.

Sometimes those styles don't have colors associated with them but when I compare the name of the run's and paragraph's styles to the styles in the styles iterator associated with the document:

```
for style in doc.styles:
    if style.name == run.style.name:
        color = style.font.color.rgb
```

The color is sometimes revealed here...
You could also do that with the paragraph.style.name instead of run.

But there are some documents that even after looking for a color in all these places I still get None everywhere.  In one such document there is a style called Default, that has a color associated with it.  Do all the other styles inherit the color from the Default style? If so, is this a unique name? How would I know which styles inherit color from which other styles?

Comment: Would probably be helpful to link to some example doc files to make an mcve

Comment: Maybe you should use another package version Otherwise check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979095/write-text-in-particular-font-color-in-ms-word-using-python-docx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that this would work, but theoretically it should solve the issue you're facing. From the `python-docx` [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

1. The `CharacterStyle` [class](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#characterstyle-objects) has attributes `base_style` and `font`.
2. Since the `base_style` object points to another `CharacterStyle` instance (or None), you can make a "nested" query until you find a `font` color.

It would look something like:

```py
style = run.style
while style:
    if style.font.color.rgb:
        color = style.font.color.rgb
        break
    else:
        style = style.base_style
```