# How do I solve docx format saving error in a python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, anaconda, save-as

I wrote code to highlight some keywords from a txt file and save the output in a docx file. The output is coming perfectly, however, when I tried to save the file, it showed some errors. The code is as below:

```
import re
from termcolor import colored
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

def mark_keywords(text, keywords):
    marked_text = text
    for keyword in keywords:
        pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(keyword))
        marked_text = re.sub(pattern, colored(keyword, 'red', attrs=['bold']), marked_text)
    return marked_text

# Set the input file name
input_file = "input.txt"

try:
    # Read input text from the file
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        input_text = file.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
    exit()

# Get input keywords from the user
input_keywords = ["we","We","This Paper","This paper", "this paper", "this Paper", "our", "Our", "this study", "This study","This Study","this research", "This Research", "This research"]

# Clean up the keywords (remove leading/trailing whitespaces)
input_keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in input_keywords]

# Mark keywords in the input text
marked_text = mark_keywords(input_text, input_keywords)


# Create a new Word document
document = Document()
    
# Split the marked text into paragraphs
paragraphs = marked_text.split("\n\n")

# Add each paragraph to the document
for paragraph_text in paragraphs:
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(paragraph_text)

# Save the document as output.docx
output_file = "output.docx"
document.save(output_file)
```

And, error is coming like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 44
     42 # Add each paragraph to the document
     43 for paragraph_text in paragraphs:
---> 44     paragraph = document.add_paragraph(paragraph_text)
     46 # Save the document as output.docx
     47 output_file = "output.docx"

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\document.py:56, in Document.add_paragraph(self, text, style)
     47 def add_paragraph(self, text='', style=None):
     48     """
     49     Return a paragraph newly added to the end of the document, populated
     50     with *text* and having paragraph style *style*. *text* can contain
   (...)
     54     break.
     55     """
---> 56     return self._body.add_paragraph(text, style)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\blkcntnr.py:37, in BlockItemContainer.add_paragraph(self, text, style)
     35 paragraph = self._add_paragraph()
     36 if text:
---> 37     paragraph.add_run(text)
     38 if style is not None:
     39     paragraph.style = style

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\text\paragraph.py:37, in Paragraph.add_run(self, text, style)
     35 run = Run(r, self)
     36 if text:
---> 37     run.text = text
     38 if style:
     39     run.style = style

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\text\run.py:163, in Run.text(self, text)
    161 @text.setter
    162 def text(self, text):
--> 163     self._r.text = text

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py:104, in CT_R.text(self, text)
    101 @text.setter
    102 def text(self, text):
    103     self.clear_content()
--> 104     _RunContentAppender.append_to_run_from_text(self, text)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py:134, in _RunContentAppender.append_to_run_from_text(cls, r, text)
    128 """
    129 Create a "one-shot" ``_RunContentAppender`` instance and use it to
    130 append the run content elements corresponding to *text* to the
    131 ``<w:r>`` element *r*.
    132 """
    133 appender = cls(r)
--> 134 appender.add_text(text)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py:143, in _RunContentAppender.add_text(self, text)
    141 for char in text:
    142     self.add_char(char)
--> 143 self.flush()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py:165, in _RunContentAppender.flush(self)
    163 text = ''.join(self._bfr)
    164 if text:
--> 165     self._r.add_t(text)
    166 del self._bfr[:]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\text\run.py:41, in CT_R.add_t(self, text)
     37 def add_t(self, text):
     38     """
     39     Return a newly added ``<w:t>`` element containing *text*.
     40     """
---> 41     t = self._add_t(text=text)
     42     if len(text.strip()) < len(text):
     43         t.set(qn('xml:space'), 'preserve')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\xmlchemy.py:273, in _BaseChildElement._add_adder.<locals>._add_child(obj, **attrs)
    271 child = new_method()
    272 for key, value in attrs.items():
--> 273     setattr(child, key, value)
    274 insert_method = getattr(obj, self._insert_method_name)
    275 insert_method(child)

File src\lxml\etree.pyx:1042, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__()

File src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi:748, in lxml.etree._setNodeText()

File src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi:736, in lxml.etree._createTextNode()

File src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi:1541, in lxml.etree._utf8()

ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

May be this error is coming from my given text. But I can't find from where exactly this error is coming from.

Can I get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are trying to save output of `colored()` from `termcolor` which adds special characters to its input text which is rendered by the terminal.

If you want to show colored output in docx, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41980620/7801965) is an example that might help!